# B2B hybris module gen does not work

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

AFter using b2b_acc recipe, i want to do module gen. like:

```
ant modulegen -Dinput.module=accelerator -Dinput.name=qqq -Dinput.package=com.fffff.sampa -Dinput.template=develop
```

but it gives error of

```
hybris "java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException": Illegal repetition near index 0 ${YMODULE_TOKEN}(.*)
```

And there is no information about how to do for b2b.

What can i do? I need to develop a b2b website. Should i use extgen?

Now it gives this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot merge namespace
>   ((fulfilmentprocess)) into (()) due to duplicate attribute
>   'ConsignmentProcess.done(java.lang.Boolean):((fulfilmentprocess))::YAttributeDescriptor[fulfilmentprocess-items.xml:18(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]'
>   vs
>   'ConsignmentProcess.done(java.lang.Boolean):((yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess))::YAttributeDescriptor[yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess-items.xml:18(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating your custom extension using modulegen, you should delete existing template extension as well in your localextension.properties file.

Remove any of the following extensions that might appear in your localextensions.xml file

```
yacceleratorcore
yacceleratorfacades
yacceleratorstorefront
yacceleratorinitialdata
yacceleratortest
yacceleratorcockpits
yacceleratorfulfilmentproces
```

Read Here for more details on how to customize Accelerator using modulegen :

https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8ace75c786691014a5e9dcafa29d5410.html

Answer (score 0):

Removing yacceleratorbackoffice work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This issue is version-dependent but try removing yacceleratorfulfilmentproces or yacceleratorbackoffice from localextensions.xml and that may help.